# How To add column to data.table without copy in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am adding columns to a data.table with

```
DT <- DT[ , c("x_next6_h", "x_last6_h", "x_h") :=
           lapply(.SD, function(x) x/100),
                   .SDcols = c("x_next6", "x_last6", "x") ]
```

but I assume this copies all the contents of DT.

Is there a way to do this transformation with less overhead?

Comment: Why are you using both `<-` and `:=`?

Comment: I don't know.  Simply referencing the data table with the new columns stores them?  Then how to avoid printing the data table to console?

Comment: When you use `:=` (assign by reference) the output isn't automatically printed.

Comment: Every time I do DT[, newvar := math] the DT is being print to console.  (using rstudio, if thats relevant)

Comment: @justincress sounds like you're using an old version of data.table.  You could update the package, or wrap `invisible()` around the call: `invisible(DT[, newvar:=math])`

Comment: sesisionInfo gives data.table_1.9.4 which I think is the most recent.

Comment: You could consider downloading the latest development version from https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table  As Ananda mentioned, you don't need to use `<-`  `:=` is assigning by reference.  In order to see the result you need to add `[]`, aka `print`, at the end of your code.